# Pytorch XOR implementation rounding issue?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, rounding-error

I've implemented the XOR problem with a super simple NN in Pytorch as a learning exercise.

The network is trained, and now that I'm giving it new inputs, looking for output, I get the following:

`print("(0, 0) = {}".format(model(Variable(torch.Tensor([0, 0]).unsqueeze(0)))))`

`print("(1, 0) = {}".format(model(Variable(torch.Tensor([1, 0]).unsqueeze(0)))))`

`7.7716e-07, 1`

Why does it output:

- 1 (*exactly* ) for the input `[1, 0]`
- 7.7716e-07 (not *exactly* 0) for `[0, 0]`

I understand it's close to it, but why isn't it, unlike the other?

Does it simply require more training?

Answer (score 0):

Probably just a formatting difference. Note that:

```
small_number = torch.tensor(1e-10)
print(small_number)
print(1 + small_number)
```

```
tensor(1.0000e-10)
tensor(1.)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Regarding your second question.

If you train more you might have results closer to rounded numbers. But keep in mind you are adjusting a function (multiparametric nn) by minimizing the loss so is unlikely you will get exactly the round number.

I've done the same exercise you did take a look on this [notebook](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/eusoubrasileiro/notebooks/blob/master/general/Pytorch%20Learning%20XOR%20Example.ipynb)